# WiX Bootstrapper UI

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.7, wix3.8

I have created a bundle with the extended WiX bootstrapper application (v3.7.4844.29798). Everything works fine, but I have a little problem. I have changed the text the user will see on the 'Progress Page'. In the .wxl-file I changed the text to 'The required program files are being copied and installed.'

When installing, the user sees "The required program files are being copied and installed." on the progress page That's OK. But when uninstalling the program the user also sees this text, because the bundle uses the progress page.

I want to have another text when installing the Bundle and then uninstalling the Bundle. Can one use a condition or something else?

Answer (score 0):

In the onDetectPackageComplete method, you can check for a PackageState presence. If a *Package* is present then this is an uninstallation that is going on else otherwise. You can refer to *[Custom WiX Managed Bootstrapper Application](http://bryanpjohnston.com/2012/09/28/custom-wix-managed-bootstrapper-application/)* for more information.